# HTML Complex list item with number+letter

Tags: html, css, html-lists

How to accomplish this:

```
  1. lorem ipsum
  2. lorem ipsum
 2a. lorem ipsum
  3. lorem ipsum
 4a. lorem ipsum
```

html: (I cannot expose the text so I'm using lorem)

```
   <ol>
     <li>lorem ipsum 1</li> <--- 1
     <li>lorem ipsum 2 </li> <--- 2
     <li class="number-alpha">lorem ipsum 2a</li> <--- 2a
     <li>lorem ipsum 3</li> <--- 3
     <li class="number-alpha">lorem ipsum 4a</li> <--- 2a
   </ol>
```

as you can see the 2a is a different situation then the 4a, but I need to solve both situations in one ordered list and use CSS instead of JS or Jquery. The reason why you have 2 and 2a is because 2a is an exceptional message of 2 for a different user. the reason why its 4a instead of 3a is because 4a isn't an exceptional message but its information for a different user (it needs to be shown in the same list)

Comment: With a single `ul` and no submenus, you cannot manage this with CSS ( either with CSS Counters or otherwise). You would need to code this manually. What is the actual HTML? Plus what happened to 4?

Comment: Paulie_D, it's the second time I see you commenting "you can't do that", please don't close the topic this time and see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what I came with (pretty proud of this one I gotta admit) :

```css
ul {
    counter-reset:yourCounter;
}
ul li {
  list-style:none;
}
ul li:not(.sub) {
    counter-increment:yourCounter;
}
ul li:before {
    content:counter(yourCounter) ". ";
}
ul li.sub:before, ul li.subskip:before {
    content:counter(yourCounter) "a. ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="sub">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="subskip">lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful. I now need to add in my own padding to make sure the text aligns like a normal List (when the text breaks up into 2 lines). Cheers!

Comment: no worry :) You could do for example left: 0px; position: absolute; on the pseudo element and left: 15px; on the li element :) Just make sure to put position: relative; to the ul tag so it doesn't place itself relatively to the page

Comment: Alright thanks for the info! will try it out whenever I get this implemented into my IOS WebView :)